# Data not consistent

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, recommender-system

I have data set of client profile and mutual funds , now the problem is there is huge numbers of different mutual funds available and based on history I can see for certain type of client profile more than 20 different funds have been suggested ?

Now I have no idea which algorithm should I use to come up with most recommended fund for certain client profile ?

Comment: What's in this history? What is it attached to; each user? What is the basis for the fund suggestions? Can you show some sample data?

Comment: If my answer is not what you are looking for, please clarify your question in depth. Otherwise upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to build a Recommendation Engine which will recommend mutual funds to the clients based on their profile. Recommender System is a special class of Machine Learning and make use of Supervised/Unsupervised Machine Learning techniques.

According to Wikipedia,

> A recommender system or a recommendation system (sometimes replacing
>   "system" with a synonym such as platform or engine) is a subclass of
>   information filtering system that seeks to predict the "rating" or
>   "preference" that a user would give to an item.

So essentially, the item here in your problem statement is the mutual fund of which you need to predict the preference a client would give. Higher rating/preference of a Mutual Fund, let's call it X for a client A will mean X should be recommended to A.

Now, how do you give rating/preference to a list of items? Recommender Systems uses a number of approaches listed below:

1. Popularity Based Approach
2. Content Based Approach
3. Collaborative Filtering Based Approach which composes of Nearest Neighbor and Matrix Factorization
4. Hybrid Approach

**Popularity Based Approach** - Popularity Based Approach will recommend items, in your case, mutual funds, based on the total count of purchases. It will rank the mutual fund with maximum purchase in the past at the top. The item at the top will be recommended to every user/client.

- Advantages of Popularity Based Approach is that it is very easy to
  implement. The approach is used to list out the most popular items in
  e-commerce websites, online news (Google News). It can use context (for example, most popular products at this time of day). It can use user and item features (for example, most popular products with feature F1, most popular products among user with feature UF1).
- Disadvantage of Popularity Based Approach: No personalized
  recommendation. Every one is recommended the same item.

**Content Based Approach** - In Content Based Approach, features of both the item as well as the user/client is used to offer personalized recommendation.

According to Wikipedia,

> Content-based filtering methods are based on a description of the item
>   and a profile of the user’s preferences.  In a content-based
>   recommender system, keywords are used to describe the items and a user
>   profile is built to indicate the type of item this user likes. In
>   other words, these algorithms try to recommend items that are similar
>   to those that a user liked in the past.

So, let's say if one of the client with features UF1, UF2 purchased a mutual fund X with a set of features F1, F2 and F3 in the past. New mutual fund products, lets say Y and Z will only be recommended to this client if their features matches with that of F1, F2 and F3. 
It is also called Classification Based Approach because you are feeding in list of features of products and user into a classifier to predict what item should be recommended. To build a Content Based Approach model, you can use Machine Learning models like Naive Bayes Classifier or a Decision Tree.

- Advantage of Content Based Approach over Popularity Based Approach is
  that it gives personalized recommendation.
- Disadvantage: It is not scalable. It is difficult to collect high
  quality information on user and product.

**Collaborative Filtering Approach** -

According to Wikipedia,

> Collaborative filtering methods are based on collecting and analyzing
>   a large amount of information on users’ behaviors, activities or
>   preferences and predicting what users will like based on their
>   similarity to other users.

Without going into technical jargons, Collaborative Filtering Approach is of two types -- **User-based Collaborative Filtering** & **Item-based Collaborative Filtering**.

In User-based Collaborative Filtering, let's say user/client A bought two items X and Y and user/client B bought the same items X and Y. So these two users are similar to each other based on their purchase history. Now if the user/client B purchases a third item Z, Z will also be recommended to user/client A.

In Item-based Collaborative Filtering, let's say a user/client A bought items W, Y and Z. User/client B bought W and Y. User/client C bought only Y. 
What will be recommended to user/client C? Answer is item W because item W was co-purchased with item Y by user/client A and B.

These comes under Nearest Neighbor techniques of Collaborative Filtering because we are trying to classify a user or an item by determining its nearest neighbor. An algorithm known as kNN (k-nearest Neighbor) is used to do the task.

There is one another technique known as Matrix Factorization as well.

**Hybrid Based Approach** - Hybrid Based Approach, as name says, is a combination of Content Based Approach and Collaborative Filtering Approach. It is used largely used by Netflix and Amazon to give best recommendations.

Comment: Thanks a lot I am using Popularity Based Approach for now let see how it works

Comment: Click the tick to accept my answer if you feel your question is answered.

Comment: Since you have understood the data and the approach , any suggestion which algo should I to predict  use I have already cleaned the data and sorted it out on popularity base

Comment: @subratshasank I need to know what are all the information you have in the client profile.

Comment: Net worth , salary , risk , investment goal , duration of investment and some more

Comment: Does the mutual funds have any predefined features? For example, type of mutual fund, rate of interest, maturity date, types of instruments, etc.

Comment: Yes they do certainly have but I have not considered them since I thought they are users input , and thanks for helping. I really appreciate that

Comment: Then you can use Content Based Approach for a starter. There are many algorithms to do this as I stated -- Naive Bayes Classifier, Decision Tree among many others. If you're new to ML, go ahead with Naive Bayes, it's easy to understand and implement. If you are concerned about accuracy and performance, go ahead with Decision Tree. You can look up for videos of how to build a recommendation engine on YouTube for a start.

Comment: Sure. No problem.

Comment: is not that Naive Bayes Classifier will only solve classification problem and I have so many number funds and there is no classes .  I mean the problem is not whether based on history one should invest or not but the problem is which fund out of 8000 funds to choose

Comment: Its a multi class classification problem which has more than 8000 classes ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39vJRxIPSxw - See if this might solve your problem.